# Updating a Structure Handle From Within a GUI Function - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a callback function for a GUI `list` that also passes in a structure from my workspace so I can update/add new values to it when the function executes.  Unfortunately, when I try and update/add to the structure, nothing happens, its like it gets lost in space.

Here is my callback function:

```
function guiUpload(upload_button_h, evt, text_h, list_h, tracks, predictions, models)

// various other code...

predictions.valence(end+1) = valence;

end
```

This works fine if I take and run my code as a script and not within a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are not changing the content of the object `predictions`, but the copy of the object. In order change the variable `predictions` you should do one of these two things:

a) you make the variable global. So what happens inside the function is reflected outside. **Note: Global variables are not a good practice in general.**

```
global predictions
function guiUpload(upload_button_h, evt, text_h, list_h, tracks, models)
// various other code...
predictions.valence(end+1) = valence;
end
```

b) your object `predictions` is an object of a class, so you make the class inheritage from `handle`. Then you are not copying the object, but giving something like a pointer to access it inside the function.

Without see the whole code no much more can be said.

Comment: Thanks, there is probably too much code which is why I have kept my post sparse.  On the other hand, option (a) sounds the most practical at this moment in time.  Can you please instruct me as to how to make my predictions structure global from my workspace?

Comment: You just make the variable global before entering the function, and then you  dont have to pass it like an argument, it will be accessible everywhere (this is what make it a bad solution)

Comment: Ah, I see, similar to `php`.  Unfortunately, I'm getting this error now: `Error: File: guiUpload.m Line: 3 Column: 1, Function definitions are not permitted in this context.`  I have also made sure `predictions` has been taken out of the `callback` property of the `uicontrol` object.  I've tried moving `global` inside the function and get this error: `Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.`

Comment: Use `global definitions` the first time you use your variable in the code, or in the main function. Not much more can be said without seing the code.

Comment: I see, I have just this minute figured this out after creating my variables from the command window first.  I have abandoned the structure for now and just gone with two normal variables and they seem to both be updating nicely.  I found it a bit strange that you cant assign a value to your global variable within the same line of declaring it.  In the mean time I'll keep experimenting and tick the answer box for your response.  So it it correct the `global` needs to be inside the function and not outside in your answer?